# Use case specification include and extend relationships

Tags: uml, specifications, use-case, use-case-diagram

I am writing out a use case specification for my use case diagrams and I am unsure whether include or extend relationships should be part of the use case specification or if it should stick to the main use cases for the application.

Comment: Stick to he main use cases. Incl/Excl are mistaken for functional decomposition which would be plain wrong.

Comment: @qwerty_so that should pretty much be an answer.

Comment: @Ister I know. I was thinking about writing a Q and A for this in order to redirect all these similar questions. I could become a SO millionaire that way ;-)